# Q&A - Print key value pairs of an object

Tags: javascript

In php you can easily print the key value pairs of an associative array like this:

```
<?php

$array = [
    "id" => "10",
    "name" => "Hans",
    "age" => 20
];


foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key \t $value \n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
id       10 
name     Hans
age      20
```

[PHP online test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c632a71f87a1716dcc5128e8def737f73fd5620c)

How does this work with JavaScript?

Note: This is a self answered question ([share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works with javascript.

```js
    var myObject = {
      name: "hans",
      id: 10,
      age: 20
    }
    
    var output = "";
    for (var key in myObject) {
     output += key + " = " + myObject[key] + "<br>";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

**Output:**

```
name = hans
id = 10
age = 20
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kk9tk9g6/)

---

### **Output Array of Multiple Objects:**

```js
var person1 = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
var person2 = {firstName:"Hans", lastName:"Oettinger", age:42};

var persons = new Array();

persons.push(person1);
persons.push(person2);

outputArray(persons);

function outputArray(pArray)
{
  var output = "";

  for(var i in pArray) {
    output += "<ul>";
      for (var key in pArray[i]) {
        output += "<li>" + key + ": " + pArray[i][key] + "</li>";
      }
        output += "</ul>";
    }
  
  $("#output").html(output);
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="output"></p>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLa4ryn4/)

Comment: You are right, but I was not satisfied with the quality of the questions and answers. There were no functional examples for example (jsfiddle etc.)